# Kendo Multiselect remove selected item from list

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am creating a project in javascript with kendo. I want to remove the selected item from kendo dropdown.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="example" role="application">
    <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
        <option>Steven White</option>
        <option>Nancy King</option>
        <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
        <option>Robert Davolio</option>
        <option>Michael Leverling</option>
        <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
        <option>Michael Suyama</option>
        <option>Anne King</option>
        <option>Laura Peacock</option>
        <option>Robert Fuller</option>
        <option>Janet White</option>
        <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
        <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
        <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
        <option>Andrew Fuller</option>
        <option>Anne Davolio</option>
        <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
        <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
        <option>Laura Fuller</option>
    </select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
        var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
          //autoClose: false
        }).data("kendoMultiSelect");
    });
</script>
```

I am getting like this

http://dojo.telerik.com/iZuhOS/2

But I want this

http://dojo.telerik.com/iPOlapaB

Comment: your question is not clear. Both examples can remove items from multiselect. Can you be more specific about your issue.

Comment: You can do it using this code. If you need a specific answer, please be more descriptive. Better if you can post your code.

<select id="multiselect">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect();
    });
</script>

Comment: @SehaxX: In my first link item is not removed and for second link item is removed from dropdown

Comment: @SehaxX: In first link it is showing selected in the dropdown but i want once user select it should not display in dropdown

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the selected options with css. Try this:

```
.k-state-selected {
  display: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OCOJUvEK)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happining because you use

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

If you replace it with

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

You need also to add some other styles to make it working:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The complete code will be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" role="application">
        <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
            <option>Nancy King</option>
            <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
            <option>Robert Davolio</option>
            <option>Michael Leverling</option>
            <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
            <option>Michael Suyama</option>
            <option>Anne King</option>
            <option>Laura Peacock</option>
            <option>Robert Fuller</option>
            <option>Janet White</option>
            <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
            <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
            <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
            <option>Andrew Fuller</option>
            <option>Anne Davolio</option>
            <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
            <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
            <option>Laura Fuller</option>
        </select>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
              //autoClose: false
            }).data("kendoMultiSelect");
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are a small issues with styling but the main issue is solved

Comment: What if you want to use the latest version?